# New Asus monitor goes blank at least once a month and needs restarting to work again

Tags: display, power-supply, hdmi

I have an **Asus ProArt PA238Q** monitor that sometimes goes blank for no reason whatsoever.

- This issue usually happens one time in 1 week or 1 month.
- When this happens, its power-LED stays on.
- It is connected via HDMI. I have changed the HDMI cable from a random
  one to a 5ft (~1.5 meters) Philips brand HDMI cable - this did not
  solve the problem.
- The only workaround is to turn the monitor off and on again.
- The issue did not occur with my former display.
- Since I have this monitor I have changed from a regular PC with a
  GeForce GPU to a MacBook Pro, so I think that this discards a graphic
  card issue.

Since this issue does not happen regularly, I do not know if the monitor has some component fault or if some other problem (house wiring, power instability) causes this behavior.

Does anybody know how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: When your monitor is either working or sleeping, if you unplug the power and plug it back in. Can you reproduce the issue?